# Android Video Strange Behaviour on amazon TV

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I am developing an android video app,in which i am playing video in loop continuously. i am playing video by using video view API ,this app is working fine on kindle fire tablets but when i play this app on amazon TV, video view stop playing video after some time with null Uri exception, and i also tried to play video with media player and Surface view but on amazon TV i am getting same problem,after some time video stop and last image is shown, any body have idea why this behavior is ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think its because of eclipse problem you have to downgrade your sdk or test it on an other system.